# How can i run a method in silverlight once a month?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a program that displays some information in the form of a chart. The information updates every month and so i need to retrieve the information once a month.

I thought about having a thread that sleeps for a months time but, i don't know if that is doable. Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the last accessed date in a file/table and then poll the file/table each day when the program starts. If it exceeds 1 month(30/31 days) then re-get your data.

Use the `DateTime` class in .NET to help you with it. Also use `DateTime.Subtract()` between two dates.

Comment: Instead of a file/table, could i just use a variable in the program stores the date when the data retrieval method was called? Then make comparisons to that variable until 30 days has passed?

Comment: @rage Don't do that. You never know when your program can close - hence its a good idea to persist critical values in a file/table

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the advice i'll try this when i get a chance.

Comment: If you have any control over the database, you could put the timestamp there instead of a separate file...

Comment: I don't have any control over the database x_x

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what you're trying to do here.  It sounds... odd.

So, where is the info coming from?  A database?  If so, can you just calculate the month's values when pulling the data normally?  Or you could have a job running in SQL Agent that updates a table once a month with the calculated values.

Really with windows you could set up a scheduled task with a similar concept.  It runs once a month and pulls down the new data.

But basically a little more info about what you're trying to do might help us give you better answers..

Comment: I am running a query to get information from a database. I am then pulling the results and plotting them onto a bar graph. The contents in the database change regularly (customer related data) and i would like for my graph to update every month without me physically running the program again. 

The charts that the program produces are going to be on TV monitors for other people to make use of soooo it would be nice i can automate this task.

Comment: So are people going to leave a TV tuned to this one bar graph 24/7 just so they can see it update once a month? Or is the computer sending out this feed just going to pull the bar graph up once in a while?

Comment: The tv will cycle through different graphs, i'm just working on one of them. But yeah, the graphs will be on the TV's 24/7. So my graph might be up for 10-12 seconds, then the next graph, and the next one, etc. This continues until the bosses decide a different use for the TV's.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen implementations where on startup a thread is started and calculates the time until the next read time. Within the thread it waits for a shutdown event to be signalled (which is fired by the app), the timeout value is the previously calculated time. Once wait is complete, if it wasn't due to shutdown event, then data is read.

However, the more common implementation that I have seen is to use scheduled tasks to load the data to the app. Although this will take longer to implement than threaded version, it should provide a more robust solution.